# Get function address from export table Linux ASM

Tags: linux, function, assembly, x86, low-level

I would like to know a way to get the address from a specific function in Linux within the executed program in Assembly (x86).

So for example I want to get the address of sleep() reading the export table somehow.

In Windows you can do so going through the PEB (http://www.ciphermonk.net/). How can I do it in Linux?

Basically what I want is going through the PLT, search for "sleep" and get the address of sleep in a register (of course everything in ASM)

Comment: You mean something like `printf("printf: %x\n", printf);`?

Comment: The executable file format is called "ELF", and the [Wikipedia page on ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) lists some common tools to inspect both executables and libraries: `readelf`, `objdump`, and others. Does that help, or do you need to *write the code* (which may be too broad for SO)?

Comment: As I said I need to get the address using assembly so I can't use any third party program  @Jongware. About David solution that is C. I need to have some assembly code that will read the GOT/PLT and in a while compare the exported names somehow until cmp "printf", GOT[i] (pseudocode )matches and get the address.

Comment: Basically what I want is going through the PLT, search for "printf" and get the address of printf in a register (of course everything in ASM)

Comment: Did you try `extern`ing the symbol as if you were going to call it in assembly, but instead of calling it, move it to a register? *E.g.*, `mov eax, printf`?

Comment: @lurker Thank you for your response but in this case I can't do that because what you said may work if I do that before compiling. In this case I am injecting the ASM code while the process is running so that's not an option

Comment: "While the process is running" implies all external references are already resolved - and the Import Table is no longer needed, and probably not accessible anymore. Your linked example *loads* the required DLLs, it does not attempt to locate a possibly already loaded one.

Comment: Read the ELF specification, write code. Alternatively, see if you have `libdl` available somehow and use `dlsym()`. Depending on circumstances, you could determine the offset to the function using external tools first, then in the code parse the base address from `/proc/self/maps` and add the offset.

Comment: There must be a way to get the address of a specific function while the program is running and the proof is that you can use GDB or IDA and see the list of libraries and their absolute position

Comment: Would using /proc/$PID/map be a possible solution? In Windows there is only one module loader and it happens to fill the PEB with loaded module information. In Linux there are different dynamic loaders, the one to use is specified in a particular ELF section. So there is not a easy to access memory area with a well defined format. You may want to study ld.so.1, libc.so.1 and ld-linux.so.1 and the ELF format to get an idea. However common used utility, like ps, use the proc fs. You can use the open/read syscall to find the glibc base address.